# functions are processed only once and then browser give error "function is not defined"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My function. I get selected index when user change item in select:

```
$(function itemchange() {
     var index = document.getElementById('columnList').selectedIndex;
     if (index != -1) {
         alert(index);
     }
 });
```

My html tags. I put select item in Panel. This Panel placed in modal window:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ModalPanel" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="500px" BackColor="GhostWhite">
    <div>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left;">
        <select size="4" id="columnList" onchange="itemchange" style="height:200px;">
            <option value="Code">Code</option>
            <option value="Name">Name</option>
            <option value="P">P</option>
            <option value="Desc">Desc</option>
            <option value="Object">Object</option>
            <option value="User name">User name</option>
            <option value="Num">Num"</option>
            <option value="Commant">Commant</option>
            <option value="Prod">Prod</option>
            <option value="Test">Test</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;">
     <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: This is not how it's done. Don't wrap the itemchange function in `$()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do:

```
$(function itemchange() {
    var index = document.getElementById('columnList').selectedIndex;
    if (index != -1) {
        alert(index);
    }
});
```

Because now the scope of the function is not in the window object.
You should do:

```
$(function(){
    itemchange();
});

function itemchange() {
    var index = document.getElementById('columnList').selectedIndex;
    if (index != -1) {
        alert(index);
    }
}
```

Then the scope for the function changes to the window object and then it gets executed when you run `itemchange()`. It will also run when the DOM is loaded (I believe you wanted that).

Comment: Yes you right. But it doesn't work. Now function doesn't running.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? And are you using jQuery anyway?

Comment: In console nothing. Yes, I use jQuery.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't run? You can try so by putting an alert just before `var index = ...`

Comment: What if you put a breakpoint just before and after `itemchange();` gets called in `$(function(){ ... }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22815/discussion-between-martin-and-user1848942)

Comment: Noting. I put breakpoint in $(function(){ ... }, in itemchange() and after itemchange().

Comment: Are you sure that your code is not cached and therefor not working? Are you also sure that your breakpoints are working at all?